# Encoding input in textarea with javascript for TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is quite complicated. I'm not able to put this into words directly. So here goes my problem -

I've this short-code generator form built upon WordPress TinyMCE editor which is basically an HTML document. It has two `<textarea></textarea>` inputs. When user clicks on "Insert short-code", javascript code on this page populates the short-code and inserts it into the editor in WordPress.

Now, if the user inserts something like -

`>>>This is an "amazing post"! You can't wait to get your hands on it.<<<`

in the one of the textarea, the short-code generates the corresponding attribute as this -

`c_text=">>>This is an "amazing post"! You can't wait to get your hands on it.<<<"`

This short-code with other attributes is then saved into database by WordPress. When it is retrieved at the front-end, the `add_shortcode()` function in WordPress messes everything up, which is quite obvious as `>,<,',"`exist inside `c_text`

An obvious choice in PHP would be to use `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES`, but how to do it in this case? Using the [phpjs equivalent function](https://github.com/kvz/phpjs/raw/master/functions/strings/htmlentities.js) would mean including lot of javascript. How to do this effectively?

**UPDATE** : I tried using the phpjs equivalent function. It does the conversion properly. But, the quotes are replaced by WordPress. 
Example - I put a random string `<> <test> <<><<<>><<> ' <"">?sdg#@Y^#ASCST#@Y^`

and did `console.log(htmlentities(string,'ENT_QUOTES'));`, it logged

`&lt;&gt; &lt;test&gt; &lt;&lt;&gt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&gt;&gt;&lt;&lt;&gt; &#039; &lt;&quot;&quot;&gt;?sdg#@Y^#ASCST#@Y^`

which is correct. But, when I viewed the switched to HTML view of TinyMCE, it showed

`&lt;&gt; &lt;test&gt; &lt;&lt;&gt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&gt;&gt;&lt;&lt;&gt; ' 
&lt;""&gt;?sdg#@Y^#ASCST#@Y^`

The quotes were replaced by TinyMCE.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [`urlencode`](https://raw.github.com/kvz/phpjs/master/functions/url/urlencode.js) function and it worked fine.